# Globe symbol in application menu

Tags: functionality

What is the meaning of the globe symbol (at the end after "z") in the application menu? And why is the symbol always deactivate?

[image]

Comment: I think it's for apps with non Latin characters as their first character (in a similar way that the # character is used for numbers), but I don't have such an app installed to verify...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's for those apps whose names start with characters not in your phone language's alphabet. So if your phone is set to a language using the Latin alphabet (like English), it will contain apps named with, for example, Chinese or Japanese characters. If, however, your phone uses a language with non-Latin letters, then it's apps with Latin letters that show up there.

Likewise, the **#** symbol at the beginning means apps whose names start with a number (e.g. 6tag or 4Blend HDR).

Both symbols are also used elsewhere in the OS, for example in the People app.

See also [this article at WPCentral](http://www.wpcentral.com/what-does-globe-icon-mean-my-windows-phone).